# Real life elastic collision and variation of kinetic energy

Tags: collision

How small should $\Delta T$ be in a collision to be considered elastic? In elastic collisions $\Delta T =0$, but as far as I know, just atomic collisions are considered perfectly elastic. Then, which criterias are used to considere a collision between two objects elastic?

Comment: Think about, where $\Delta T$ goes, and which other energy scale you could compare $\Delta T$ with.

Answer (score 1):

As with so many other things this is about precision, scale of effects, and what you need to model.

Physicists treat real-world events with theories that they don't *exactly* qualify for all the time. The trick is knowing when to do it. And the short version is *when the failure to qualify is too small to matter to the way you are going to use the results*.

Let's say you are trying to predict impact-parameter vs. opening angle relationship for a moving on still air-hockey puck collision. If you expect the energy loss (transfer to non-kinetic channels) to be less than one percent (not entirely unreasonable) but your velocity measurements are coarser than 1% you simply can't detect the failure or elasticity without examining a statistical sample anyway. You can ignore the fact that the system isn't *really* elastic.

On the other hand, if you are looking at, say, a Newton's cradle arrangement and want to ask how it behaves on a time scale of minutes, then the say order of 1% energy loss matters to you. You treat the collisions as slightly as inelastic and that lets you model the decay of the amplitude of the swing.

Answer (score 0):

A collision is considered to be elastic if both momentum and kinetic energy is conserved. Thus:
$$m_{1i} v_{1i} + m_{2i} v_{2i}=m_{1f} v_{1f} + m_{2f} v_{2f}$$ and $$\frac 12 m_{1i} v_{1i}^2 + \frac 12 m_{2i} v_{2i}^2=\frac 12 m_{1f} v_{1f} + \frac 12 m_{2f} v_{2f}$$

There's practically no collision that's truly perfectly elastic in the real world, and the third law of thermodynamics confirms that (no system can be 100% efficient), but physicists find it more convenient to approximate things that otherwise won't qualify into a definition of a process. All collisions in the macroscopic world are approximations to an elastic collision, and even at the atomic scale, collisions are still not perfectly elastic, but they're close as we can possibly get. To know when to consider a collision approximately elastic in the real and macroscopic world, you've got to have a huge portion of the system's kinetic energy intact at the end of the process, like the collision of two tennis balls can be said to be approximately elastic.

Comment: As I said before, that just happens in atomic collisions, I'm asking for real-world collisions.

Comment: You asked for criterias and those are the criterias. You want more, your question should be edited to include your further questions.

Comment: Actually there isn't exactly a perfectly elastic collision in real world, but the atomic collisions, as you said, is the closest we could get to a idealized perfectly elastic collision. In the macroscopic world, there exist no perfectly elastic collision, we only approximate some collisions that happens to conserve a large fraction of the kinetic energy in the system.

Comment: Seriously, repeating the textbook definition to someone who is asking how to make a practical application to cases that don't qualify in the exact formulation is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @ Dmckee. To be fair, the OP actually asked for criterias for a collision being elastic and I gave him straight it. And it isn't textbook copied sir, not only textbooks can do that.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you copied the equation, but that what you have written would be suitable in an introductory textbook. But the question contains a subtext (which seemed clear to me) that the OP *already knows* the textbook definition and additionally has noticed that macroscopic events don't really have that character but that we use the notion anyway. He's asking how to know *when* to use the notion in a cases that aren't exactly elastic.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that. That makes the difference between you and I. Thanks for the insight.